# how to send C2DM registration ID to App Server 

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm

Ive manage to implement an android app (From the C2DM tutorial) to retrieve the device's registration ID but I have no idea now to send it to my application server. Can anyone guide me to how i can do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You already have communications established from your Android app to your application server (e.g., HTTP) -- otherwise, C2DM will do you little good. Use whatever you are already using to communicate from your Android app to your application server to send the registration ID to the application server.

Comment: Ive only starting implementing this app and it currently has no communications with the server and i dont know how to do so. Ive read a few articles on HTTP Post but there arnt any clear guidelines on implementing them.

Comment: @ISL: Worrying about C2DM before setting up HTTP communications with the app server is like worrying about chrome wheel rims on a car before getting an engine. There are also approximately 1000 times more books, articles, blog posts, and samples on HTTP operations in Java (using `java.net`/`HttpURLConnection` and Apache HttpClient, both available in Android) than there are examples of C2DM in Android. The `java.net` stuff has been around for more than a decade, for example.

Comment: @ISL: http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html